# Discord.js looking for nonexistent directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm writing a Discord Bot with Discord.js and I'm making the bot send a random image from a set:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
   if (msg.content === 'I Hate It'){
       const randImg = ['https://i.imgur.com/C0gR27R.png', 'https://i.imgur.com/qErVhIm.jpg'];
       msg.channel.send("", { files: randImg[Math.floor(Math.random() * randImg.length)]});
   } 
});
```

However when I run the code and type "I Hate It", nodemon gives me this error:

```
(node:13) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/container/h'
(node:13) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

According to the error, It's trying to look for a directory that doesn't exist but nowhere in the code is it told to look for a directory. I know that it's that particular block because all other commands and part of the bot work without error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to send a file, since it's not on your device, you can just send the link. Discord will turn the imgur link into a photo

```
msg.channel.send(randImg[Math.floor(Math.random() * randImg.length)])
```

Comment: I forgot that you can just send constants as constants, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The 'files' propriety of the MessageOptions object is an array. Maybe, adding the arrays brackets should solve your issue.

```
client.on('message', msg => {
   if (msg.content === 'I Hate It'){
       const randImg = ['https://i.imgur.com/C0gR27R.png', 'https://i.imgur.com/qErVhIm.jpg'];
       msg.channel.send("", {
         files: [ // bracket
           randImg[Math.floor(Math.random() * randImg.length)]
         ] // bracket
       });
   } 
});
```

---

Helpful links:

[MessageOptions | discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions)

[TextChannel#send | discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send)